# TextInput Background changes to white in the first ,Once it is active or blurred ,it took the corresponding color I have Provided

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

Trying to get the desired backgroundcolor for Text input from react-native-paper

Hello, I've been trying to achieve Facebook login page using React Native. Like this[image]
But when I try to use background color for Text Inputs it is not taking the color give. It is showing like this[image]

My code is,

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-paper";

const SignIn = () => {
  const [mail, setMail] = React.useState("");
  const [pass, setPass] = React.useState("");
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const CustomStyle = focus ? styles.TextInputFocus : styles.textField;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignContent: "center" }}>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={CustomStyle}
          label="Mobile number or email"
          value={mail}
          mode="outlined"
          onChangeText={(mail) => setMail(mail)}
          theme={{
            colors: {
              placeholder: "white",
              text: "white",
              primary: "white",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
            },
          }}
          //   editable={false}

          onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
          //   onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
          onTextInput={() => setFocus(false)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <TextInput
          style={CustomStyle}
          label="Password"
          value={pass}
          mode="outlined"
          onChangeText={(pass) => setPass(pass)}
          theme={{
            colors: {
              placeholder: "white",
              text: "white",
              primary: "white",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
            },
          }}
          onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text
            style={{
             
            }}
          >
            Log in
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignIn;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textField: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontSize: 17,
    color: "#E2DED0",
    ackgroundColor: "#647C90",
    borderColor: "#E2DED0",
    padding: 10,
  },
  TextInputFocus: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    borderColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "#647C90",
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    // height: 50,
  },
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 5,
    // justifyContent: "center",
    // alignContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Where did I done wrong. And ignore the touchable Opacity Its still in progress.

Comment: there's also an `:active`  state of an input field, maybe also add styles for that or reuse the ones of focus.

Comment: In your textField style it's written `ackgroundColor`. You forgot a `b` in there

Comment: @LucasP.Luiz Thanks for the help. I'll check and get back to you for further assistance

Comment: @LucasP.Luiz The spelling mistake cost me a day. Thanks for your keen observation. It settled my error